# Python3 reading Japanese characters in a pickle file made in python2

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, pickle

I use the code below to read a pickle file made in python2

```
import pickle
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
    data_df = pickle.load(fin, encoding='latin1')
```

Everything works well except the column including Japanese charactors.

For example, string supposed to be "東京都" may become something like "æ±äº¬é".
I think python3 reads the `bytes` format string as `str`. How can I convert it back?

Here is some test I did in python3

```
>>> a='\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac\xe9\x83\xbd'
>>> b=b'\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac\xe9\x83\xbd'
>>> a
'æ\x9d±äº¬é\x83½'
>>> b
b'\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac\xe9\x83\xbd'
>>> print(a)
æ±äº¬é
>>> print(b)
b'\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac\xe9\x83\xbd'
>>> a.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
>>> b.decode('utf-8')
'東京都'
```

I think `pickle.load` reads the utf-8 code as `str` (like the `a` case above).

[EDIT]
The reason why I set `pickle.load` encoding to `latin1` was because there's column with datetime format. It causes error if I set `encoding='utf-8`

Comment: 1) Do you have a [MCVE] for the code that produced the pickle? 2) Why did you specify `encoding='latin1'` in the `pickle.load` call if you know you were pickling UTF-8 encoded bytes? Presumably you would want to pass `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: when I use `encoding='utf-8'`, there's error like `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 31184: invalid start byte`

Comment: You probably didn't have consistent encodings then. Best you can do is load with `encoding='bytes'`, then manually decoding appropriately for each resulting `bytes` object.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried `pickle.load(fin, encoding='bytes')`, and get the error `TypeError: __new__() keywords must be strings`. It's raised in `python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py` so maybe pandas problem

Comment: I think as you said, there might be multiple encoding in the file. the problem of the Japanese character is to solved by setting `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: Now I know why `encoding='utf-8'` doesn't work because there's `datetime` format data in the column!